# Application defined or object defined error - depending on which Worksheet is opened

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue that I am struggling to solve as it's a bit specific. I have code that does copy and paste from one sheet to others. Each part of the code basically copies part from the master sheet "current" to the specified sheet.

When I run my code I receive an error "Application defined or object defined error" and the code stops at the work sheet "Dividend yield" after the following line

```vb
Worksheets("div. yield").Range("B7").Select
```

However if I open the sheet "Dividend yield" and run my code from there it will work fine until the last sheet "Reverse PE" where it will again throw and error "Application defined or object defined error" after the line

```vb
Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B9").Select
```

I guess the error is related to the next coming rows with Autofill method but I have not found any useful solutions to this problem. Could somebody please advise me how to solve this error?

Full macros code is below.

```vb
Function getYield() As Double
    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE
    .Navigate "http://uk.investing.com/rates-bonds/world-government-bonds"
    .Visible = False
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementById("pair_23705")
    Dim myValue As Double: myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(2).innerHTML
    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing
    Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B7").Value = myValue
    Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B7").Value = Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B7").Value / 100

End Function

Sub adjust()
    Dim copyAdress As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Median As Range


    '''PE'''
    Set copyAdress = Worksheets("current").Range("A1:CJ10000").Find("PE_RATIO", lookat:=xlPart)
    lastRow = Cells(65536, copyAdress.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Set copyRange = Worksheets("current").Range(Cells(copyAdress.Row + 1, copyAdress.Column), Cells(lastRow, copyAdress.Column))
    Worksheets("PE").Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
    copyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("PE").Range("B7", "B" & lastRow)
    Worksheets("PE").Range("B2").Value = Worksheets("current").Range("A1").Value
    Worksheets("PE").Range("B3").FormulaArray = "=MEDIAN(B7:B" & lastRow + 2 & ")"
    Worksheets("PE").Range("B5").Font.Bold = True
    Worksheets("PE").Range("B5").FormulaArray = "=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP($A$5,$A$7:$HI$1750,COLUMN(B4),FALSE)),VLOOKUP($A$5,$A$7:$HI$1750,COLUMN(B4),FALSE)," & Chr(34) & NA & Chr(34) & ")"
    Set copyRange = Worksheets("current").Range("A5", "A" & lastRow)
    copyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("PE").Range("A7", "A" & lastRow + 2)


    ''Dividend yield'''
    Set copyRange = Worksheets("current").Range("A5", "A" & lastRow)
    copyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("div. yield").Range("A7", "A" & lastRow + 2)
    Worksheets("div. yield").Range("B7").FormulaArray = "=IF(ISNUMBER(current!X5),current!X5," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
    Worksheets("div. yield").Range("B7").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("div. yield").Range("B7:B" & lastRow + 2), Type:=xlFillDefault


    '''PE Forward'''
    Set copyAdress = Worksheets("current").Range("A1:CJ10000").Find("P/E-Ratio 03E", lookat:=xlPart)
    lastRow = Cells(65536, copyAdress.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Set copyRange = Worksheets("current").Range(Cells(copyAdress.Row + 3, copyAdress.Column), Cells(lastRow, copyAdress.Column))
    Worksheets("PE_forward").Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
    copyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("PE_forward").Range("B7", "B" & lastRow + 2)
    Worksheets("PE_forward").Range("B2").Value = Worksheets("current").Range("A1").Value
    Worksheets("PE_forward").Range("B3").FormulaArray = "=MEDIAN(B7:B" & lastRow + 2 & ")"
    Worksheets("PE_forward").Range("B5").Font.Bold = True
    Worksheets("PE_forward").Range("B5").FormulaArray = "=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP($A$5,$A$7:$HI$1750,COLUMN(B751),FALSE)),VLOOKUP($A$5,$A$7:$HI$1750,COLUMN(B751),FALSE)," & Chr(34) & NA & Chr(34) & ")"
    Worksheets("PE_forward").Columns("B").Replace What:="#VALUE!", Replacement:=""
    Worksheets("PE_forward").Range("B3").NumberFormat = ""
    Set copyRange = Worksheets("current").Range("A5", "A" & lastRow)
    copyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("PE_forward").Range("A7", "A" & lastRow + 2)


    '''Reverse PE'''
    Set copyRange = Worksheets("current").Range("A5", "A" & lastRow)
    copyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Reverse_PE").Range("A9", "A" & lastRow + 4)
    Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B2").Value = Worksheets("current").Range("A1").Value
    Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B5").FormulaArray = "=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP($A$5,$A$9:$HI$1750,COLUMN(B751),FALSE)),VLOOKUP($A$5,$A$9:$HI$1750,COLUMN(B751),FALSE)," & Chr(34) & NA & Chr(34) & ")"

    getYield
    Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B3").FormulaArray = "=MEDIAN(B9:B" & lastRow + 4 & ")"

    Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B9").FormulaArray = "=IF(ISNUMBER(PE!B7),1/PE!B7," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
    Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B9").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B9:B" & lastRow + 4), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B3:B" & lastRow + 4).Select
    Selection.Style = "Percent"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```

Comment: Once you have it working as you'd like, I'd suggest posting a review question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com where you'll get loads of advice...

Comment: But in short,, minimize the number of cell selections (you don't need to change the selection unless changing the selection is your actual aim. Minimize the number of times you read from and write to cells, it all takes time - better to work in memory and transfer data to and from the sheets as arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the select method unless the sheet is first active, so add this line:

```
Worksheets("div. yield").Activate
Worksheets("div. yield").Range("B7").FormulaArray = "=IF(ISNUMBER(current!X5),current!X5," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
```

and later at:

```
Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Activate
Worksheets("Reverse_PE").Range("B9").Select
```

There are much faster and more maintainable ways of doing what you're trying to do, but the above sheet activation will solve your immediate problem.

Don't forget to activate each sheet before you try to select one of the cells on it.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Maybe you can point me to some methods how i can optimize my code?